# Missing data on main views from filtered views on GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I create a views for my subdomain on my Google Analytics, but I cant see the same data on my main views. By normal, the data on my sub domain views are data which filtered from the main views, but it's not. How do I include the data on my sub domain view on my main view? Or is there any filter that I accidentally created on my main views?

Thank youuuu :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a coding issue. Please post this to Webmasters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Only reason you might not be able to see the data is due to fact that there are any filters setup in main view that are excluding the data. Please review your filters, or create a new view without any filters setup.

hope this help